# How to add custom config file to app/config in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, configuration

I want to add `custom_config.php` to *app/config* directory of my Laravel 5 project, but can't find any article explaining this process. How is this done?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can easily add a new file to the config folder. This file should return configuration values. Check other config files for reference. Say `constants.php` is like so

```
<?php

return array(
    'pagination' => array(
           'items_per_page' => 10
    ),
);
```

You can now access this config file from anywhere by either using the **Config** Facade or the `config()` global function like so

```
Config::get('constants.pagination.items_per_page');
```

or

```
config('constants.pagination.items_per_page');
```

i.e.

```
config('file_name.variable_name');
```

Comment: We need to run `php artisan config:cache` after creating new config file otherwise it is not loaded.

Comment: stop caching your configuration on development, there is no need

Comment: In lumen you need to add it to your bootstrap/app.php file. $app->configure('config_filename');

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many times one might need to create a config file, but here you have an Artisan command for it: https://gist.github.com/jotaelesalinas/eafd831048ca5fb5fba970afd1921f70